# HTTP status code response when there is not matched data with DB

Tags: api, http

I am building an `API` about email auth code.

Its process is simple.

1. input random code (client browser)
2. request with input code. (client browser)
3. receive the request (server)
4. scan the code from DB (server)
5. there is no code matched (server)
6. return a response with `status code`.

There are many `status code`, (2xx, 4xx, 5xx);

but I don't know which status code number is the most proper for this case.

Comment: It depends on what semantics you want to give your request. Is the assumption that the code must exist and it not existing is a *failure*? Or that you're checking whether a *resource exists* (i.e. it would warrant a "404 Not Found" if missing)? Or that you're merely doing a *search* and "no result" is an entirely valid form of result?

Comment: It is just normal `REST API` like a login situation with the wrong password.

Comment: I have no experience with `API` so I just want to know someone's use-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the semantics you want to give your request. E.g.:

1. The API should search for items matching the query and return a list of results, like `GET /codes?q=4ba69g`. Think a "search page". In this case, an empty result `[]` is a perfectly valid result; nothing was wrong with the query, it just didn't return any matches. That's a `200 OK`, or maybe a `204 No Content` if you want to omit the empty response body entirely.
2. The code is treated like a resource, e.g. `GET /codes/4ba69g`. In this case a missing code would result in a `404 Not Found`.
3. It's an action you want to perform which may fail, e.g. `POST /login`. If the user supplied the wrong credentials/code and hence the action cannot complete, that's a client-side error and therefore a `400 Bad Request`.